# can't solve latches

Tags: fpga, vhdl, latch, encryption

I would like to ask if someone could help me with some latches in my desing. I am working with an aes encrypt core taken from opencores and  I have described in vhdl the surrounding system to introduce an get the data to the core. When I simulate it, my design works properly but when I program my FPGA with the system's bitstream and I communicate whith it via hyperterminal It doesn't return me the correct encrypted data. I have tryed to many things to solve it but I don't manage to find the error, I was thinking that maybe some latches that there are in the system could be the problem. I post here just the lines were the latches are.

PD: the core communicates with zynq via axi and I am using  a ZedBoard Zynq Evaluation and Development Kit (xc7z020clg484-1)
[image]

state control: latch in next_state

```
  begin  
    if (rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK)) then
    if (S_AXI_ARESETN='0')then
      actual_state <= wait_state;
   else 
      actual_state <= next_state;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

data input enable: latch in a<=Avalid_data_I; and b <= Avalid_key_I;

```
process (S_AXI_ARESETN, S_AXI_ACLK) 
        begin  
            if (rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK)) then
                 if (S_AXI_ARESETN='0')then
                    a<=  '0';
                    a1<= '0';
                    b <= '0';
                    b1 <= '0';
                 else
                    a<=Avalid_data_I;
                    a1<= a;
                    b <= Avalid_key_I;
                    b1 <= b;
                    c <= valid_data;
                    c1 <=c;
                 end if;
            end if;
    end process;
```

finally I have a latch when I build the output: dat_encrip is a the output from the encryption core taken from opencores and out_encrypt is a internal register that will be read from the zynq.

```
      out_encrypt (31 downto 24) <= dat_encrip when (cnt=0 and    dato_valido= '1');
      out_encrypt (23 downto 16) <= dat_encrip when (cnt=1 and valid_data= '1');   
      out_encrypt (15 downto 8)  <= dat_encrip when (cnt=2 and valid_data= '1');
      out_encrypt (7 downto 0)   <= dat_encrip when (cnt=3 and valid_data= '1');
```

Thank you for your help and sorry If you find it difficult to understand me, because my English in not enough good.

Comment: You have identified some latches. Do you want to get rid of them, but then also simulation changes? Or do you want some timing constraints, so that the latches behave the same in hardware as in the simulation? Did you checked that the communication itself is correct?

Comment: Remove the reset from your sensitivity list.

Comment: I have removed the reset but it doen't work, about the timing constrains, I haven't defined any constains,I have a clock frecuency of 50MHz ehich value shall I define for my constrains?

Comment: The communication works properly, I set the values for the encryption from a C program in SDK and they are OK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether the latches really are your problem, but those lines end up in latches:

```
out_encrypt (31 downto 24) <= dat_encrip when (cnt=0 and dato_valido= '1');
out_encrypt (23 downto 16) <= dat_encrip when (cnt=1 and valid_data= '1');   
out_encrypt (15 downto 8)  <= dat_encrip when (cnt=2 and valid_data= '1');
out_encrypt (7 downto 0)   <= dat_encrip when (cnt=3 and valid_data= '1');
```

Take a look at the first line, for example:

```
out_encrypt (31 downto 24) <= dat_encrip when (cnt=0 and dato_valido= '1');
```

This will assign a new value to `out_encrypt(31 downto 24)`, but only when `cnt=0 and dato_valido= '1'`. If this expression evaluates to false, there's nothing new to assign to `out_encrypt(31 downto 24)` -- the synthesis tool will not have a choice but build a latch to store the old value. In other words, you will need an else clause here to assign an illegal value or do the assignments in a clocked process (ie. assign to a register).

More generally, any assignment that's not inside a clocked process and that does not specify a new value for every input combination will end up as a latch.

Comment: I have written this but the latch continues:                                                                out_encrypt (31 downto 24) <= dat_encrip when (cnt=0 and     valid_data= '1') else
                                                         out_encrypt (31 downto 24);

Comment: Your new code does not solve the problem: you still ask the synthesis tool to build combinational logic (remember: there's no clock in this process!) that stores the old value; the only difference is that now, you explicitly ask for it by doing `x <= ... else x;` instead of implicitly by not assigning a new value. One way to solve this would be to do `x <= ... else (others => '0');` -- this will remove the latch, but it's probably not be what you want to achieve. If you really need to store the data, you need flip flops, ie. you need to move the assignments to a clocked process.

Comment: I introduce the clock and the latch dissapeared, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something is not good with your process, it is written in a mixed way of process with async reset and sync reset. It is also missing reset for c and c1. I think that, for sync reset which Xilinx recommends, it should be:

```
process (S_AXI_ACLK) 
    begin  
        if (rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK)) then
             if (S_AXI_ARESETN='0')then
                a<=  '0';
                a1<= '0';
                b <= '0';
                b1 <= '0';
                c <= '0';
                c1 <= '0';
             else
                a<=Avalid_data_I;
                a1<= a;
                b <= Avalid_key_I;
                b1 <= b;
                c <= valid_data;
                c1 <=c;
             end if;
        end if;
end process;
```